# Reading XML and keep DOM model in memory

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Due to the very limited documentation of JDOM's `detachRootElement`, I have doubts about the best way to read an XML and keep the dom tree in memory if that is for read-only purposed.

What's commonly used is something like this:

```
public class .... {
   Element stored = null;

   private void load() {
    // Build the document with SAX and Xerces, no validation
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    // Create the document
    Document doc = builder.build(file);
    stored = doc.getRootElement();
   }
}
```

(This can throw an exception, but I've left that out for clarity).

Knowing that `stored` is a class variable, it's unclear if doc will be kept in memory or can be garbage collected after this. If so, is `detachRootElement` a possible solution to this?

Comment: Hey Steven, sorry, just checking something: If you have a class variable that holds a reference to an Element (Root Element) of the obj "doc", then how are you expecting it to be GC'ed? http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/jdom/org.jdom.Document-source.html

Comment: I'm not keeping a reference to doc, only to stored, hence my question if doc will be garbage collected. So, I guess GC on doc is only possible when I detach the element from the doc?

Answer (score 1):

The java garbage collector will not affect any used references. As long as you have a direct or indirect reference to the content of `doc`, it will not be affected by garbage collection.

Comment: Indeed, but is there still a reference to doc after the method ran? Or would I have to detach the element first?